# In a 3D monogame project, how do I place an object a set distance in front of the camera?

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, monogame

I am working on a monogame project in which the player controls a ship in space (first person) and shoot asteroids that are spawned at random locations with random velocity. When I shoot, I want to place my bullet object 1.5 units directly in front of my camera no matter where the camera is or which direction it is facing. I have tried this line

`Vector3 torpedoPos = CameraPosition + CameraDirection * 1.5f;`

as these two posts suggest: [Placing objects right in front of camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858950/placing-objects-right-in-front-of-camera), [Placing an object in front of the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696782/placing-an-object-in-front-of-the-camera), but as soon as my position is anything other (0, 0, 0) the object is placed in the same location no matter what direction I am facing. In the line of code I posted, torpedoPos is the position I want to spawn my bullet object, CameraPosition is the current position of the camera object in 3d space and CameraDirection is a unit vector with the direction the camera object is facing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with this line of code
`Vector3 torpedoPos = CameraPosition + Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, Orientation * 1.5f);`
The orientation is the matrix which holds which direction my ship is facing. By doing a transform with the orientation * 1.5 and Vector3.Forward, I get an amount to add to my current position that will place the torpedo directly in front of the ship.